# Extract details from Integrity error in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm getting integrity error from Django in below format

```
ForeignKeyViolation('insert or update on table "foo_bar" violates foreign key constraint "foo_obj_product_id_97ae618a_fk_designman"\nDETAIL:  Key (product_id)=(9bb7fd8c-2ed2-4a75-ab08-c749459a5097) is not present in table "foo_product".\n'
```

Is there any inbuilt method to extract the "details"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sys` module provide `exc_info()` method to access exception details:

```
try:
    # code that raise IntegrityError
except IntegrityError:
    exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
    print(exc_type) # <class 'django.db.utils.IntegrityError'>
    print(exc_tb.tb_lineno) # line that raised the exception
    print(exc_obj.args) # list of arguments that are displayed as exception message
```

You can play with the returned objects and extract what you need.